# Stop scrolling/excess space if sidebar toggled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a strange issue where excess space is appearing when my sidebar menu is toggled in mobile view - as seen below.

[image]

It seems to be a problem with the template I'm using which you can see here:

LIVE PREVIEW:

http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

SOURCE CODE:

http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/simple-sidebar/

I have tried `overflow-y: hidden` on several elements to no avail. I've also tried resizing `html,body{}` with no luck. I'm not sure what's causing the excess space.

The sidebar is set to `height:100%`. The `background-colour` stops where it should, leaving me to think it's a margin or padding issue with the sidebar. Maybe not.

Your help would be greatly appeciated.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug created by the padding-left used in #wrapper.

But this is a very odd implementation for this animation.

You can fix this by simply adding **position:relative** and replacing **padding-left** for **left**.

Code to replace:

```
#wrapper {
    position:relative;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
   left: 250px;
}
```

[I made an example](http://codepen.io/luisjoserivera/pen/BzdoLo) of a better way of achieving the same goal and avoid future problems that your implementation may bring.